# 'Pre-prepared' statements in SQLite3?

Tags: sqlite

Using SQLite in a memory-constrained embedded system with a fixed set of queries, it seems that code and data savings could be made if the queries could be 'pre-prepared'.  That is, the prepared statement is produced by (an equivalent of) sqlite3_prepare_v2() at *build* time, and only _bind(), _step() etc need to be called at runtime, referencing one or more sqlite3_stmt* pointers that are effectively static data.  The entire SQL parsing (and query planning?) engine could be eliminated from the target.

I realise that there is considerable complexity hidden behind the sqlite3_stmt* pointer, and that this is highly unlikely to be practical with the current sqlite3 implementation - but is the concept feasible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was [discussed](http://www.mail-archive.com/sqlite-users@sqlite.org/msg17562.html) on the SQLite-users mailing list in 2006. At that time D. Richard Hipp supported a commercial version of SQLite that ran compiled statements on a stripped down target, which did not have any SQL parser. Perhaps you could check with [hwaci](http://www.hwaci.com/sw/sqlite/prosupport.html) to see if this product is still available.