# SQ LITE reduction of size for embedded system

Tags: sqlite, embedded

I have been working on this project for quite a while, while SQ Lite is the smallest database system for all uses, it is quite big and bulky for embedded. So I am looking for a way to reduce the size of its library. Is there a way to remove all the join functionalities? As my project only uses SQ Lite as a source of faster  file access and storage. With only one database used and only the functions of select, insert, and delete used. Sorry new to using SQ Lite.

Edit: Sorry I didn't clarify. I used all the omit options already and picked out the ones that work, the size only went down by 200k. I was hoping for more ways to reduce the size before i go into the actual SQ Lite code and start remove function, or a pointer to how to remove function in the SQ Lite code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Minimize SQLite library size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6664709/minimize-sqlite-library-size)

Comment: Start going through the options listed [here](https://www.sqlite.org/compile.html) that disable features.

Comment: Maybe you could use something else. What is your embedded environment? Could you be more precise on what kind of features you need?

Comment: You need to specify a target size.  You could be told all the ways of reducing the footprint only to find that your expectations or requirements are not feasible; in which case you will have wasted everyone's time.

Comment: Was the reduction of 200k the change in the library size or the change in the size of your fully linked executable?  If you are statically linking, only the direct and indirect interfaces referenced by your application will be linked.  If you are dynamically linking the runtime RAM footprint will not be the same as .so file size, since again only the direct/indirectly referenced modules will be loaded.  Removing unused code from the library may have no impact whatsoever, because it was never linked to your application in the first place.

Comment: I was hoping for like reducing the libsqlite3.so file from 2.8M to like a size of around 2 M hopefully. Sorry for not making it clear, kinda new to this project

Comment: On SO clarify by editing the question rather than by adding a comment.  It is not a discussion forum.  Still not clear where your resource constraint is; the size of the .so file relates to the space used in the file system, not necessarily the RAM footprint - this my be an unnecessary and fruitless optimization or some arbitrary target you have determined without any real justification.

Comment: It unfortunately doesn't lead directly to a practical answer, but [this rather old question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970720/pre-prepared-statements-in-sqlite3) considers one possible avenue of exploration.